# How to pass a parameter from one role to the next in ansible

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook, from which I would like to call 2 roles:

1. Start and provision my db ec2 instance
2. Start my web ec2 instance, and set the "db-ip" to the ip of the first instance

So in the first playbook I use the "ec2" module, which returns a lot of information, including its ip.

Can I somehow pass this ip to the next role?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can store the IP in [a variable](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html):

```
┌─[jamesph@ilmr] - [~/temp/ansible] - [Wed Sep 28, 12:28]
└─[$]> cat provision.yaml 
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - shell: echo 'so cool'
      register: message

- hosts: localhost
  roles:
    - example
┌─[jamesph@ilmr] - [~/temp/ansible] - [Wed Sep 28, 12:28]
└─[$]> tree roles
roles
└── example
    └── tasks
        └── main.yaml

2 directories, 1 file
┌─[jamesph@ilmr] - [~/temp/ansible] - [Wed Sep 28, 12:28]
└─[$]> cat roles/example/tasks/main.yaml 
- debug:
    msg: "got message: {{ message }}"
┌─[jamesph@ilmr] - [~/temp/ansible] - [Wed Sep 28, 12:28]
└─[$]> ansible-playbook provision.yaml  
 [WARNING]: Host file not found: /etc/ansible/hosts

 [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available


PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [command] *****************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [example : debug] *********************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "got message: {u'changed': True, u'end': u'2016-09-28 12:28:51.493133', u'stdout': u'so cool', u'cmd': u\"echo 'so cool'\", u'start': u'2016-09-28 12:28:51.489753', u'delta': u'0:00:00.003380', u'stderr': u'', u'rc': 0, 'stdout_lines': [u'so cool'], u'warnings': []}"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=4    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

The [AWS detailed guide](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/guide_aws.html) provides examples of registering the results of the `ec2` module and using it for later tasks.